# Long processing time of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have about 5M records/rows in my dataframe and I need to perform a rolling aggregation using groupby on different time frames (3 months down to 1 day).

An example of the syntax I'm using is as bellow:

```
df.groupby(by='New_ID').resample("M")["is_approved"].sum().rolling(3).sum().rename("N_App_3M").fillna(0)
```

Unfortunately it takes inconveniently too much time.

Any inputs and ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Resampling can be slow. Break this one-liner into several lines and profile runtime of each line.